# How to add a row of data (from a 2x32 matrix) to a pivot table (generated from a 11x770 matrix)?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have the following pivot table, which shows the maximum activities (values) of various radionuclides (columns) measured on various dates (rows).

[Pivot Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KuWU.png)

This pivot table was generated from an 11x770 matrix of data. However, some of these radionuclides have an "activity limit" associated with them (e.g. for Americium-241, the limit is 0.14 pCi/ L). These limits are contained in a 2x32 matrix on a separate spreadsheet (32 rows of [chemical]:[corresponding limit]). To the bottom of my pivot table, I'd like to add a row that contains the activity limit for the radionuclide in each column, and I'd like this row to exist as part of the pivot table so that I can:

1) create calculated fields like "max divided by limit"

2) don't have to worry about issues created by overlapping data when I expand or collapse rows in the pivot table

Is there any way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: To add new Row/ Column to PT,,  use Calculated Field then refresh the PT, will adjust new Row/Column. Or you need to add New Row/Column to source data and redraw the PT. Or,, add the table (source data) to Data Model and use DAX formula for New Row/Column and refresh the PT.

Comment: @Rajesh S, I also confused this question, could you please kindly explain how to use DAX formula in Data Model? Thanks. So far, I have tried to add **corresponding limit** in data source of my sample, then create a PT, and group data to achieve the layout as Brandon needs, but I could not create the calculated fields in group item.

Comment: @EmilyHua,,, if possible share the data set you have been used so far help me to apply new formula☺